# Php - concat arrays

Tags: php

i'm developing a EDI reader, but i'm just stuck on PHP thing, not reading the data.

I have the next if that reads the data and calls a function that shows on a table.

```
if ($padrao == "COARRI" && $sendername == "TPG"){
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri(trim($arquivo));
            $b = fnc_processa_coarri_header(trim($arquivo));
            $merg = array_merge($a, $b);
            prc_mostra_coarri($merg, $entry);
            //copy($path, $Uploaded.$entry);
            //unlink($path);                

}
```

My fnc_processa_coarri returns me an array, this is the code:

```
function fnc_processa_coarri($p_arquivo){
    $segmento = fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($p_arquivo, "UNB");
    $ini = strpos($p_arquivo,"EQD",0);
    $fim = strpos($p_arquivo,"NAD+CF",0);
    for( $i = 0; $i <= substr_count($p_arquivo, "EQD")-1; $i++ ) {
        $parte = substr($p_arquivo,$ini,$fim-$ini);

        if ($i == 0) {
            $a = ['Sender'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,2,0)],
                  'Recipient'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,3,0)],
                  'DateDoc'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,4,1)],
                  'TimeDoc'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,4,2)],
                  'IdSender'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,5,0)],

                  'PortLoad'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+9",5),2,1)],
                  'PortDischarge'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+11",6),2,1)],
                  'Operator'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+CF",6),2,0)],
                  'Agent'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+AG",6),2,0)],
                  'EquipQualif'=>[fnc_resgata_qualif_equipamento(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),1,0))],
                  'EquipIdent'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),2,0)],
                  'SizeType'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),3,1)],
                  'Category'=>[fnc_resgata_categoria(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),5,0))],
                  'Status'=>[fnc_resgata_status(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),6,0))],
                  'Booking'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+BN",6),1,2)],
                  'BL'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+BM",6),1,2)],
                  'OwnerCargo'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+AAE",7),1,2)],
                  'ExecutionDate'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+203",7),1,2)],
                  'PositionOnVessel'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+147",7),2,1)],               
                  'FinalDest'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+7",5),2,1)],
                  'TareWeight'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+T",9),3,2)],               
                  'TareWeightUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+T",9),3,1)],               
                  'GrossWeight'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+G",9),3,2)],              
                  'GrossWeightUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+G",9),3,1)],              
                  'Seal'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "SEL"),1,0)],                             
                  'TypeSeal'=>[fnc_resgata_tipo_lacre(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "SEL"),2,0))],
                  'IdealTemp'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TMP"),2,1)],
                  'IdealTempUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TMP"),2,2)],
                  'MinTemp'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,2)],
                  'MaxTemp'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,3)],
                  'MinMaxTempUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,1)],
                  'OverDmsFrontLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsFrontWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsFrontHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,4)],
                  'OverDmsFrontUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,1)],             
                  'OverDmsBackLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsBackWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsBackHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,4)],
                  'OverDmsBackUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,1)],              
                  'OverDmsRightLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsRightWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsRightHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,4)],
                  'OverDmsRightUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,1)],             
                  'OverDmsLeftLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsLeftWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsLeftHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,4)],
                  'OverDmsLeftUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,1)],              
                  'OverDmsGenLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsGenWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsGenHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,4)],                
                  'OverDmsGenUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,1)],                                               
                  'OverDmsExtLen'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,2)],
                  'OverDmsExtWid'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,3)],
                  'OverDmsExtHei'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,4)],
                  'OverDmsExtUnit'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,1)],              
                  'ModeTransp2'=>[fnc_resgata_modo_transp(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),3,0))],             
                  'TranspMeans2'=>[fnc_resgata_transp_means(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),4,0))],                           
                  'CarrierCode2'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),8,1)],
                  'Responsible'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),8,4)],
                  'Damage'=>[fnc_determina_dano(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DAM"),1,0))],
                  'DamageCode'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DAM"),5,0)],
                  ];        
        }
        else {
            array_push($a["Sender"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,2,0));  
            array_push($a["Recipient"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,3,0));   
            array_push($a["DateDoc"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,4,1)); 
            array_push($a["TimeDoc"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,4,2)); 
            array_push($a["IdSender"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte($segmento,5,0));    
            array_push($a["Seq"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "BGM"),2,0));  
            array_push($a["FunctionMsg"], fnc_resgata_funcao_mensagem(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "BGM"),3,0)));                     
            array_push($a["PortLoad"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+9",5),2,1)); 
            array_push($a["PortDischarge"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+11",6),2,1));   
            array_push($a["Operator"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+CF",6),2,0));    
            array_push($a["Agent"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+AG",6),2,0));   
            array_push($a["EquipQualif"], fnc_resgata_qualif_equipamento(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),1,0)));  
            array_push($a["EquipIdent"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),2,0));   
            array_push($a["SizeType"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),3,1));     
            array_push($a["Category"], fnc_resgata_categoria(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),5,0)));      
            array_push($a["Status"], fnc_resgata_status(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "EQD"),6,0)));       
            array_push($a["Booking"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+BN",6),1,2));     
            array_push($a["BL"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+BM",6),1,2));      
            array_push($a["OwnerCargo"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RFF+AAE",7),1,2));     
            array_push($a["ExecutionDate"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+203",7),1,2));              
            array_push($a["PositionOnVessel"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+147",7),2,1));               
            array_push($a["FinalDest"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "LOC+7",5),2,1));        
            array_push($a["TareWeight"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+T",9),3,2));       
            array_push($a["TareWeightUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+T",9),3,1));       
            array_push($a["GrossWeight"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+G",9),3,2));      
            array_push($a["GrossWeightUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "MEA+AAE+G",9),3,1));      
            array_push($a["Seal"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "SEL"),1,0));     
            array_push($a["TypeSeal"], fnc_resgata_tipo_lacre(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "SEL"),2,0)));     
            array_push($a["IdealTemp"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TMP"),2,1));        
            array_push($a["IdealTempUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TMP"),2,2));
            array_push($a["MinTemp"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,2));              
            array_push($a["MaxTemp"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,3));
            array_push($a["MinMaxTempUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "RNG"),2,1));
            array_push($a["OverDmsFrontLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsFrontWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsFrontHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,4));      
            array_push($a["OverDmsFrontUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+5",5),2,1));     
            array_push($a["OverDmsBackLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsBackWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsBackHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,4));
            array_push($a["OverDmsBackUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+6",5),2,1));      
            array_push($a["OverDmsRightLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsRightWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsRightHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,4));
            array_push($a["OverDmsRightUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+7",5),2,1));     
            array_push($a["OverDmsLeftLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsLeftWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsLeftHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,4));
            array_push($a["OverDmsLeftUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+8",5),2,1));      
            array_push($a["OverDmsGenLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsGenWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsGenHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,4));
            array_push($a["OverDmsGenUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+9",5),2,1));       
            array_push($a["OverDmsExtLen"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,2));
            array_push($a["OverDmsExtWid"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,3));
            array_push($a["OverDmsExtHei"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,4));
            array_push($a["OverDmsExtUnit"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DIM+10",6),2,1));
            array_push($a["ModeTransp2"], fnc_resgata_modo_transp(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),3,0)));
            array_push($a["TranspMeans2"], fnc_resgata_transp_means(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),4,0)));
            array_push($a["CarrierCode2"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),8,1));
            array_push($a["Responsible"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT+1",5),8,4));
            array_push($a["Damage"], fnc_determina_dano(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DAM"),1,0)));
            array_push($a["DamageCode"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DAM"),5,0));
        }
        $ini = strpos($p_arquivo,"EQD",$fim);
        $fim = strpos($p_arquivo,"NAD+CF",$ini);
        $resultado = $a;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

And my other function called fnc_processa_coarri_header is this:

```
function fnc_processa_coarri_header($p_arquivo){
    $segmento = fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($p_arquivo, "UNB");
    $ini = strpos($p_arquivo,"UNH",0);
    $fim = strpos($p_arquivo,"UNT",0);
    for( $i = 0; $i <= substr_count($p_arquivo, "UNH")-1; $i++ ) {
        $parte = substr($p_arquivo,$ini,$fim-$ini);
        if ($i == 0) {
            $a= ['Move'=>[fnc_resgata_tipo_movimento(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "BGM"),1,0))],
                 'ModeTransp1'=>[fnc_resgata_modo_transp(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),3,0))],              
                 'TranspMeans1'=>[fnc_resgata_transp_means(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),4,0))],                
                 'Voyage'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),2,0)],                
                 'VesselName'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,4)],
                 'Arrival'=>[fnc_formata_data(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+132",7),1,2))],
                 'Departure'=>[fnc_formata_data(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+133",7),1,2))],
                 'Carrier'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+CA",6),2,0)],
                 'CarrierCode1'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),5,1)],              
                 'VesselId'=>[fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,1)],              
                 'TypeId'=>[fnc_resgata_tipo_id_navio(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,2))],                 
                 ];     
        }
        else {
            array_push($a["Move"], fnc_resgata_tipo_movimento(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "BGM"),1,0))); 
            array_push($a["ModeTransp1"], fnc_resgata_modo_transp(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),3,0))); 
            array_push($a["TranspMeans1"], fnc_resgata_transp_means(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),4,0)));   
            array_push($a["Voyage"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),2,0));   
            array_push($a["VesselName"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,4));   
            array_push($a["Arrival"], fnc_formata_data(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+132",7),1,2)));  
            array_push($a["Departure"], fnc_formata_data(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "DTM+133",7),1,2)));    
            array_push($a["Carrier"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "NAD+CA",6),2,0)); 
            array_push($a["CarrierCode1"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),5,1)); 
            array_push($a["VesselId"], fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,1)); 
            array_push($a["TypeId"], fnc_resgata_tipo_id_navio(fnc_edi_recupera_compnte(fnc_obter_linha_segmento ($parte, "TDT"),8,2)));    
        }
        $ini = strpos($p_arquivo,"UNH",$fim);
        $fim = strpos($p_arquivo,"UNT",$ini);
        $resultado = $a;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

I know those two functions are a little big, but my point i want is concat those two arrays to show on a table. But on the result, it only appears the first line with the correct values, the rest does not and show this error.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 510
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 513
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 514
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 515
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 516
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 517
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 518
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 519
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 523
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EDI\tpg.php on line 524
```

These lines are from my table, the 1 increase depends of the number of data on each file. (For eg. In one file y got undefined offset: 5).

The error lines are the these:

```
<td>'.$p_array["Move"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["VesselName"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["Voyage"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["CarrierCode1"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["TypeId"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["VesselId"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["ModeTransp1"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["TranspMeans1"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["Arrival"][$i].'</td>
<td>'.$p_array["Departure"][$i].'</td>
```

Sorry for the long post, i'm a java guy, these php code i'm trying to understand, but really no clue.

**UPDATE**

Being more specific, The array that returns the function `fnc_processa_coarri` has multiple positions and the array that returns the function `fnc_processa_coarri_header` has one position. What i want is that the data of the header function repeat by each position of the function `fnc_processa_coarri`

Comment: It's not a solution to the problem, just a coding suggestion: Instead of `if/else` every time through the loop, create the result array with empty sub-arrays before the loop, then push onto each of them in the loop. Then you don't have to duplicate so much code.

Comment: You also don't need to do `$resultado = $a;` each time through the loop. Just `return $a;` after the loop.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the size of the sub-arrays returned by `fnc_processa_coarri` is not the same as `fnc_processa_coarri_header`. So  there's no `$p_array["Move"][1]`. Look at `var_dump($merg);`

Comment: @Barmar About $resultado, yeah, i forgot to set $a, i was testing another things and forgot to delete that. I did the var_dump and it only appears  `["Move"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Descarga" }` Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution finally

On the block of if i had to do these.

```
if ($padrao == "COARRI" && $sendername == "TPG"){
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri_header(trim($arquivo));
            $a = fnc_processa_coarri(trim($arquivo)) +$a;
            prc_mostra_coarri($a, $entry);          
}
```

And fix on my function `fnc_processa_coarri_header` i had to fix the value on the FOR statement.

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= substr_count($p_arquivo, "EQD")-1; $i++ ) {
```

Previously it was "UNH", and by these, it only shows the first row and not all the rows. This problem was by the .EDI file, not so much on php file.